# Why are some transactions lost during mining?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

I open mine in my own private chain, and I submit the transaction at the same time. Some of the transactions do not trade hashing, and then the fair is lost. Why?

Comment: Transaction is not guaranteed to be mined, this is basically up to miners.  Until mined, transaction resides in memory pool, that is not preserved when node is shut down and restarted.  So in case all nodes of your private blockchain were down simultaneously (very probable for private blockchain with small number of nodes), transactions from memory pool were lost.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details about the transactions or how are they generated is hard to say exactly what is happening. A possibility is some transactions have the same nonce.

Transaction have a **nonce** field that is the number of transactions from the account sending the transaction.

You can submit two or more transactions with the same nonce, but only one will be confirmed in the blockchain.